# Boolean Functions with p,q,r

Tags: boolean-algebra

Please give me feedback for my answer to this question.

**Question: (1)** Are the boolean functions $(p \land \neg q) \lor ( \neg r \land q)$ and $(p \lor \neg q) \land (r \lor \neg q)$ equal?. Explain your answer.

*My Answer: -*

No, they are not equal because they are different. By computing $p=1, q=1, r=1$ into the functions, then $(p \land \neg q) \lor ( \neg r \land q) = 0$ and $(p \lor \neg q) \land (r \lor \neg q) = 1$.  Therefore, they are not equal because their outcome is different.

Same if I compute $p=0, q=0, r=0,$ they will not equal.

Comment: That's really difficult to read because you mix logical conjunctions with natural language particles.

Comment: Yeah, it was.  I've added $\LaTeX$ to make things clearer.

Answer (score 2):

Your reasoning is completely correct. You have demonstrated a counterexample (two, in fact) to the proposition that the two expressions are equal.